# A question about gerunds

Tags: gerunds

If someone say "non-radiating objects"...
Does he mean : objects that do not have emission of radiation ?

If yes, why do we not say "non-radiator objects" ? What is the difference?

Comment: Yours is a question about usage, and not about gerunds. (See RS's answer below for an explanation of why your example doesn't contain a gerund.) *Radiate* means to spread out from a central point, which is why it's specifically the verb for radioactive substances, but that means that "non-radiating objects" could be those not fanned out from a central source. We don't say "non-radiator objects" because *radiator* already has meanings as something that cools car engines and heats rooms. You're talking about "non-radioactive objects" or "radioactively-inert objects."

Comment: Forget the term 'gerund'. The prefix "non" in "non-radiating" yields a negative verb phrase functioning as attributive modifier "objects".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all words that end in **ing** are gerunds. And in the phrase **non-radiating objects**, **radiating** is not a gerund.

So your question is based on a misunderstanding. (But yes **a non-radiating object** would be an object that does not emit radiation.)

A gerund is a verb form that functions as a noun. In your example **radiating** functions as an adjective, modifying **objects**; it's known as a **participial adjective**.

Whether a verb form is a gerund or a participial adjective depends on how it is used. For example, in the following sentences words ending in **ing** are used as gerunds:

> His asking her to marry him came as a great surprise.
>   They loved swimming in the sea.
>   The quality of her singing impressed the audience.

But the **ing** words in the following expressions are functioning as adjectives, not gerunds:

> A boiling kettle
>   A leaking tap
>   A sprinting athlete
>   An aching muscle

Although we often combine two nouns (whether as a single word, hyphenated or in sequence), so that the first functions as an adjective (toothbrush, shoe-lace, coffee mug) the combination **radiator object** is not in common use.

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm
https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-compound.htm
https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-participial-adjective-1691486

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, only two questions, 1 - is the word hacking in "ethical hacking" a gerund or not? 2 - What is the difference between "implementing security is not easy" and "security implementing is not easy"?

Comment: It is a noun. We do not modify a gerund with an adjective.

Comment: See the following for a guide on whether to modify a gerund with an adverb or an adjective: : https://www.reddit.com/r/grammar/comments/4wtxyk/adjectives_modifying_a_gerund/

Comment: I'd say that the _ing_ words in your last four examples are verb phrases, not adjectives. In your first three examples, "asking is a verb, "swimming" is ambiguous between a verb and a noun, though verb preferred, and "singing" is of course a noun.